# Garbage Collection statistics in Java Flight Recorder result

Tags: java, garbage-collection, performance-testing, jfr, java-mission-control

We have a job in our CI that kicks off our Java app and run some test (the test acts as a client to the app). The app is started with what I think is the correct JVM option to do continuous flight recording:

```
-XX:+UnlockCommercialFeatures -XX:+UnlockDiagnosticVMOptions -XX:+FlightRecorder -XX:FlightRecorderOptions=dumponexit=true,dumponexitpath=/tmp/application-flightRecorder.jfr -XX:StartFlightRecording=defaultrecording=true,settings=customSetting -XX:+DebugNonSafepoints
```

It is producing the JFR file fine, and I can open it in Java Mission Control.
In addition to the JVM option above, we also have the option to enable GC logging:

```
-XX:+PrintGCApplicationConcurrentTime -XX:+PrintGCApplicationStoppedTime -XX:+PrintGCDateStamps -XX:+PrintGCDetails -XX:+PrintFlagsFinal -XX:+PrintHeapAtGC -XX:+PrintReferenceGC -XX:+PrintTenuringDistribution -XX:+PrintSafepointStatistics -XX:PrintSafepointStatisticsCount=1 -XX:+LogVMOutput -XX:LogFile=/tmp/application-safepoint.log -Xloggc:/tmp/application-gc.log
```

Which is also fine. The gc log & safepoint log files are produced. 
However, I noticed that the GC stats in mission control doesnt list all the GCs that have occurred during the applciation lifetime. E.g. if I open the gc log using GCViewer (https://github.com/chewiebug/GCViewer), there is significantly more GCs happening.

Have I missed something here? Or does mission control only print "significant" gc ?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Do you have an exempel of a GC that does not appear in the flight recording? Some JFR events have a duration threshold, I can’t remember right now if that applies to the GC events though.

Comment: Unfortunately I dont think i can share the JFR log (since it might contains hints to proprietary code). But I can see from the GC table (within mission control) that the GC ids start with 1, 2, then it jumps to about 50. This suggests to me that some of them are not displayed. Either not captured at all, or captured but being filtered by mission control...

Answer (score 1):

JFR uses a ring buffer, so at some point events for old GCs are flushed out, but you should not get a gap.

I noticed that you use a custom JFC-file, could it be that you have disabled some GC events, for instance, young collections?

You may want to consider writing the recording to disk (disk=true) and set maxage=1h (or what you need) to ensure that old events are not flushed out.